# Scheduling the opening of Chrome on EC2 startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I currently am using the ec2 API to launch an instance of windows server.  When the instance has started, I want to open up chrome to a specific webpage before I need to RDP into the server for a specific profile.  I have tried setting up a task scheduler and working with user scripts to do this, but I haven't had any luck getting to work properly.  What would be the best way to start up a program right when an instance starts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to not launch chrome when the instance starts (having chrome running serves no purpose if no user is logged in), more likely you want to run a program when a user starts an RDP connection:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770821.aspx